# How do I persistently load a kernel module in Fedora 20?

Tags: kernel-modules, fedora

I have successfully followed the instructions for setting up 802.1q VLAN tagging in Fedora. Now I need to make sure that when I reboot the 8021q kernel module is loaded again.

Should I be doing this through `/etc/sysconfig/modules` as instructed [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html) or should I be doing this through `/etc/rc.modules` as instructed [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html)? Or is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for `Fedora`, both methods will work, there is no guarantee to chose which one is preferable.

For `Redhat/Centos`, you should use `/etc/sysconfig/modules`, since when it's documented in [Redhat documentation - Persistent Module Loading](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Persistent_Module_Loading.html).

Another way you can use `/etc/modules.conf` in `Redhat/Centos` base distro. If you use `Debian` base distro, use file `/etc/modules` file instead.